# HTML styling while Angular JS is loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have html block and I want to control it's visibility by Angular variable

```
<div class={{visibilityCss}}>
    Show/Hide Area
</div>
```

In angular I have `$scope.visibilityCss = 'hide'` or `$scope.visibilityCss = 'show'` which is `'hide'` by default. I also have css for `.show/.hide` classes to toggle the div visibility with display:block/none.

I want this `div` to be hidden initially but my problem is that while the page is loading the div is visible and only after ~1 sec (when angular js is loaded) it is hidden by javascript. I would like to make it not visible from the very beginning. (something like applying hidden css for `.{{visibilityCss}}` class if it was a valid css class name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, first up your HTML code is bad. You should be using `ng-class` instead:

```
<div ng-class="visibilityCss">
  Show/Hide Area
</div>
```

To answer your question, Angular has a built in setup for exactly this feature.
By adding the class `ng-cloak`, and adding the following CSS to your stylesheet, it'll be hidden when the page loads. Angular will then show it once everything is loaded.

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

And then in your HTML:

```
<div class="ng-cloak" ng-class="visibilityCss">
  Show/Hide Area
</div>
```

**Edit** As mentioned by [Chandresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3283616/chandresh-r-m), using the `ng-show` directive with a true/false value would be a better option than using `ng-class`

Comment: alternatively you can put your angular script tag in the `<head>` of the page, then the page won't load at all until angular is already loaded.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe That also stifles page loading.

Comment: It does indeed, which I eluded to. My angular apps are very little without angular (most of the content is inside a `ui-view`), so I really don't mind if the page doesn't start to load until angular has - it makes very little difference, and is much easier than messing around with `ng-cloak`.

Comment: I need to apply some dynamic styles as well when it is visible so I think this solution will fit better than combining class with hide/show. Let me try

Comment: @jonasnas you need at least this solution, semantically it also makes sense to have `ng-class` **and** `ng-show` on the element, it also decouples your logic from your display a bit more.

Comment: I've tried to use ng-class with class='hide' (my one class rather than ng-cloak') and it works as well. In my case I don't want to use show/hide because It has more states like hidden/visible1/visible2 and I don't want to manage one more parameter.

Answer (score 4):

To get show/hide feature

```
<div ng-show="show">
   Area
</div>
```

In controller define

```
 $scope.show = true //Shows the Area
```

or

```
$scope.show = false //Hides the Area
```

depending on the requirement.

**EDIT**

I believe this could help, if further clarification is needed post a Plnkr.

*NOT TESTED*

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.run(function($rootScope) { 
  $rootScope.show = false;
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($rootScope,$scope) { 
   $rootScope.show = true 
})
```

Comment: Agreed that this is a better approach and is clearer in the html.

Comment: Good to know but it doesn't solve the problem for page loading.